# Extracting a value from a file that is organized into columns and rows

Tags: linux

I have a file with five columns formatted as such:

```
1 213 1 545 0.0988697879 0.9084867680
```

There are 300 rows like this. I would like to take values from column four and five of a row and perform mathematical operations, then save the result, and repeat that process with all 300 rows.

So far the closest thing to a solution I have found is building an array with the command

```
while IFS= read -a line; do   printf "Line number %d:\n" $i;   printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}";   let i++; done < "workfile.txt""
```

What are better ways to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Fields can be manipulated with awk, more info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html). The following one-liner sums 4th and 5th fields and saves the result in the output file:

```
awk '{print $4 + $5}' input.file > output.file
```

Comment: what if I wanted to divide files. that same command seems to not work with division. Instead an output is given as to a "fatal division by zero" error even though values in file are not zero

Comment: Could you provide the exact line of the file that causes this error message?